# How would I create a shortcut for an argument?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to find out how to create shortcuts for arguments for a while now, but I can't find anything online for some reason.

Let's say you wanted to, `alert('Hello World')` but you did not want to have to type alert and instead something like, `exampleshortcut('Hello World')`. Would this be possible, or am I just being dumb?

Comment: you may have a look to [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

Comment: How is the second chunk of code better than the first?

Comment: `const exampleshortcut=window.alert;` - not that it would make much sense

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to alias functions then you could just assign it to a variable, though this is generally considered an anti-pattern if you are making no other changes.

```
const exampleShortcut = alert;
exampleShortcut('Hello World');
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first-class objects. You can copy them just like any other value.

```js
const lert = alert;

lert("Hello, world");
```

Note that doing so may break functions which depend on [the `this` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Your example case won't though.

Comment: That would be `lart` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the function to a "reference". (but i think you should not).

```
a = alert;
a('Hello world');
```